# Change the icon of LiveChat Inc Widget when using the library for Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, widget, chat, livechat

[image]

`<LiveChatWidget license="17036235" key={"live-chat-widget"} />`

I want to change the icon when I first enter my website, but I don't see a library that supports changing the icon. Is there any other way to change this icon?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@livechat/widget-react

I didn't see any support from the library so I tried getting the card Id but it didn't work.